# Stopping and Looping Shell After One wav. file is Played

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, ubuntu

This is the script I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(/list/of/directories/*)

echo -e "Play wav? <y/n>"
read ANSWER
if [ $ANSWER = "y" ]

then
    rhythmbox "%s\n" "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"
fi
```

So far this is what I have. This script goes in a file of songs and starts playing a random song and continues playing random songs. I would like to have a script that plays one song then stops and then goes back to the top of the script and asks the user y or n again and then goes though the script again and again and again. Will someone please tell me how I can amend my script to do what I would like it to do?

Comment: I don't see how this plays multiple songs. It looks like it should play just one random song and stop.

Comment: Well it starts up rhythmbox and then continues to play songs randomly through rhythmbox.

Comment: You only gave one filename to rhythmbox, where does it get the other songs from?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop that loops forever. If the user doesn't enter 'y', break out of the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(/list/of/directories/*)

while :
do
    echo -e "Play wav? <y/n>"
    read ANSWER
    if [ $ANSWER = "y" ]
    then
        rhythmbox "%s\n" "${files[RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}"
    else 
        break
    di
done
```